# Android Java Identify "this." or child class calling in a parent function

Tags: java, android

In my parent class :

```
// ParentActivity.java
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    if (this instanceof ParentActivity) connectToGoogleAnalytic("parent");

    // do something else

    super.onResume();
}
```

In child class:

```
// ChildActivity.java extent ParentActivity
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if (this instanceof ChildActivity) connectToGoogleAnalytic("child");
    super.onResume();
}
```

The case is if the activity is `ChildActivity`, then when calling `onResume`, it will call the `ParentActivity's` `onResume` as well, instead of calling `ChildActivity's` `onResume` and mess up the analytics' data. I tried using instanceof to check if `this` equals `ParentActivity` but it is not working.

Comment: In such a case, after the `if` block in parentA.java, why dont you directly call the child's  `connectToGoogleAnalytic()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ChildActivity extends ParentActivity then an instance of ChildActivity is both a ChildActivity and a ParentActivity.

Since you're calling super.onResume you can just remove

```
if (this instanceof ChildActivity) connectToGoogleAnalytic();
```

from ChildActivity.onResume

Comment: For this case, analytics will show the user reading ParentActivity instead of ChildActivity?

Comment: No, If you override connectToGoogleAnalytic in ChildActivity, then calling connectToGoogleAnalytic inside ParentActivity will still execute the ChildActivity method for ChildActivity objects. In java polymorphism is automatically used http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html